# Java Multithreading - More Threads That Do Less, or Fewer Threads that Do More?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

**EDIT**: This question might be appropriate for other languages as well - the overall theory behind it seems mostly language agnostic. However, as this will run in a JVM, I'm sure there's differences between JVM overheads/threading and those of other environments.

**EDIT 2**: To clarify a little better, I guess the main question is which is better for scalability: to have smaller threads that can return quicker to enable processing other chunks of work for other workloads, or try to get a single workload through as quickly as possible? The workloads are sequential and multithreading won't help speed up a single unit of work in this case; it's more in hopes of increasing the throughput of the system overall (thanks to Uri for leading me towards the clarification).

I'm working on a system that's replacing an existing system; the current system has a pretty heavy load, so we already know the replacement needs to be highly scalable. It communicates with several outside processes, such as email, other services, databases, etc., and I'm already planning on making it multithreaded to help with scaling. I've worked on multithreaded apps before, just nothing with this high of a performance/scalability requirement, so I don't have much experience when it comes to getting the absolute most out of concurrency.

The question I have is what's the best way to divide the work up between threads? I'm looking at two different versions, one that creates a single thread for the full workflow, and another that creates a thread for each of the individual steps, continuing on to the next step (in a new/different thread) when the previous step completes - probably with a NodeJS-style callback system, but not terribly concerned about the direct implementation details.

I don't know much about the nitty-gritty details of multithreading - things like context switching, for example - so I don't know if the overhead of multiple threads would swamp the execution time in each of the threads. On one hand, the single thread model seems like it would be fastest for an individual work flow compared to the multiple threads; however, it would also tie up a single thread for the entire workflow, whereas the multiple threads would be shorter lived and would return to the pool quicker (I imagine, at least).

Hopefully the underlying concept is easy enough to understand; here's a contrived pseudo-code example though:

```
// Single-thread approach
foo();
bar();
baz();
```

Or:

```
// Multiple Thread approach
Thread.run(foo);
when foo.isDone()
    Thread.run(bar);
    when bar.isDone()
         Thread.run(baz);
```

**UPDATE**: Completely forgot. The reason I'm considering the multithreaded approach is the (possibly mistaken) belief that, since the threads will have smaller execution times, they'll be available for other instances of the overall workload. If each operation takes, say 5 seconds, then the single-thread version locks up a thread for 15 seconds; the multiple thread version would lock up a single thread for 5 seconds, and then it can be used for another process.

Any ideas? If there's anything similar out there in the interwebs, I'd love even a link - I couldn't think of how to search for this (I blame Monday for that, but it would probably be the same tomorrow).

Comment: If you're spinning off new threads only to have the parent thread wait for the child thread to complete, what exactly are you gaining?

Comment: You're right - I meant to cover that as well and completely skipped it. I'll update.

Comment: If you want things to run faster, break out simultaneous rather than sequential tasks into separate threads.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - I get that; in this case though, the given workflow is sequential. However, other instances of the workflow will execute at the same time, so would it be better to have the threads execute smaller workloads in a chunk and be more readily available for other instances of the workflow?

Comment: Much too broad. Look up amdahl's law. also JCIP would be a good thing to read.

Comment: Even considering a system with infinite processor-cores and ideal conditions for threading, you will still reach a point where the loss to *overhead* outweighs the gain of distributing the load. So really, it all depends on your specific environment and/or project.

Answer (score 2):

Multithreading is not a silver bullet. It's means to an end.
Before making any changes, you need to ask yourself where your bottlenecks are, and what you're really trying to parallelize. I'm not sure that without more information that we can give good advice here.

If foo, bar, and baz are part of a pipeline, you're not necessarily going to improve the overall latency of a single sequence by using multiple threads.

What you might be able to do is to increase your throughput by letting multiple executions of the pipeline over different input pieces work in parallel, by letting later items to travel through the pipeline while earlier items are blocked on something (e.g., I/O). For instance, if bar() for a particular input is blocked and waiting on a notification, it's possible that you could do computationally heavy operations on another input, or have CPU resources to devote to foo(). A particularly important question is whether any of the external dependencies act as a limited shared resource. e.g., if one thread is accessing system X, is another thread going to be affected?

Threads are also very effective if you want to divide and conquer your problem - splitting your input into smaller parts, running each part through the pipeline, and then waiting on all the pieces to be ready. Is that possible with the kind of workflow you're looking at?

Comment: I think your comment about increasing the throughput is what I'm targeting. Keeping with the example, if the 3 calls take 5 seconds each, then it'll take at least 15 seconds to process a single input. Since it's sequential, there's nothing I can do about that. But would breaking it up into multiple threads allow the service to handle more requests easier than tying up individual threads for the full 15 seconds, or would it be better to just focus on getting the individual items out as quickly as possible?

Comment: If you have a mix of fast and slow items, then it may make sense to "put down" large work items and "pick them back up" later. But if all jobs are roughly the same amount of work, it probably doesn't make sense not to finish one once you've started it.

Comment: @Mcory: Are any of of the steps blocked on waiting for an external event? And do additional concurrent requests for the same resource in turn slow down or break the first request?
If your computation is just heavy in terms of CPU load, your machine isn't really idle, so extra threads won't make throughput necessarily better. If, on the other hand, requests are sitting around and waiting for notifications, then just having each input go through the pipeline in a different thread might be good enough.

Comment: If you want to limit the number of concurrent accesses to the same resource, then you may want to consider better splitting. For example, say that no more than two threads can perform bar() at the same time. In that case, it might make sense to have each part of the pipeline run with separate threads so that you can make more progress on foo() and baz() while no bar()s are available. But that assumes that you're not going to end up with a backlog

Answer (score 1):

If you need to first do `foo`, then do `bar`, and then do `baz`, you should have one thread do each of these steps in sequence. This is simple and makes obvious sense.

The most common case where you're better off with the assembly line approach is when keeping the code in cache is more important than keeping the data in cache. In this case, having one thread that does `foo` over and over can keep the code for this step in cache, keep branch prediction information around, and so on. However, you will have data cache misses when you hand the results of `foo` to the thread that does `bar`.

This is more complex and should only be attempted if you have good reason to think it will work better.

Comment: I generally agree, but I would point out that trying to keep code in cache would be considerably more complex that the question's proposed example of just breaking up each job into a few parts.  The question's example would still assign the parts to processors randomly, and would likely increase rather than decrease cache misses.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single thread for the full workflow.

Dividing up the workflow can't improve the completion time for one piece of work:  since the parts of the workflow have to be done sequentially anyway, only one thread can work on the piece of work at a time.  However, breaking up the stages can delay the completion time for one piece of work, because a processor which could have picked up the last part of one piece of work might instead pick up the first part of another piece of work.

Breaking up the stages into multiple threads is also unlikely to improve the time to completion of all your work, relative to executing all the stages in one thread, since ultimately you still have to execute all the stages for all the pieces of work.

Here's an example.  If you have 200 of these pieces of work, each requiring three 5 second stages, and say a thread pool of two threads running on two processors, keeping the entire workflow in a single thread results in your first two results after 15 seconds.  It will take 1500 seconds to get all your results, but you only need the working memory for two of the pieces of work at a time.  If you break up the stages, then it may take a lot longer than 15 seconds to get your first results, and you potentially may need memory for all 200 pieces of work proceeding in parallel if you still want to get all the results in 1500 seconds.

In most cases, there are no efficiency advantages to breaking up sequential stages into different threads, and there may be substantial disadvantages.  Threads are generally only useful when you can use them to do work in parallel, which does not seem to be the case for your work stages.

However, there is a huge disadvantage to breaking up the stages into separate threads.  That disadvantage is that you now need to write multithreaded code that manages the stages.  It's extremely easy to write bugs in such code, and such bugs can be very difficult to catch prior to production deployment.

The way to avoid such bugs is to keep the threading code as simple as possible given your requirements.  In the case of your work stages, the simplest possible threading code is none at all.